# How to extract time form POSIXct and plot?

Tags: r, plot, posix

Here I have a data frame which looks like following way,with the first column `"POSIXct"` and second `"latitude"`

```
> head(b)
                sample_time latitude
3813442 2015-05-21 19:02:41 39.92770
3813483 2015-05-21 19:03:16 39.92770
3813485 2015-05-21 19:14:30 39.92433
3813515 2015-05-21 19:14:59 39.92469
3813550 2015-05-21 19:15:30 39.92520
3813585 2015-05-21 19:16:00 39.92585
```

Now,I want to plot `latitude` vs `sample_time`, with x axis representing 24 hours timestamp within a single day and group `latitude` by different days.
Any help will be appreciated!Many thanks.

Comment: Did you find the solution to your problem?

Comment: Yes. but not actually the way you suggested. Thanks anyway!!!^_^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to define "day", as opposed to the full time. Then you need to figure out what you mean by "group" ... let's just say you want to aggregate and take the daily mean. Third, you need to make the plot.

```
b$day <- round.Date(b[,"sample_time"], units="days")
b_agg <- aggregate(list(sample_time=b[,"sample_time"]), by=list(day=b[,"day"]), FUN=mean)
plot(b_agg)
```

Edit:

Just an additional thought, if you didn't want to aggregate, you could skip the second step, and change the third to `plot(b[,"day"], b[,"latitude"]`. Alternatively, you may even want something like `boxplot(latitude~day, data=b)`.